# How can I change this form of dictionary to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm now processing tweet data using python pandas module,
and I stuck with the problem.

I want to make a frequency table(pandas dataframe) from this dictionary:

```
d = {"Nigeria": 9, "India": 18, "Saudi Arabia": 9, "Japan": 60, "Brazil": 3, "United States": 38, "Spain": 5, "Russia": 3, "Ukraine": 3, "Azerbaijan": 5, "China": 1, "Germany": 3, "France": 12, "Philippines": 8, "Thailand": 5, "Argentina": 9, "Indonesia": 3, "Netherlands": 8, "Turkey": 2, "Mexico": 9, "Italy": 2}
```

desired output is:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(?????)
>>> df

Country      Count
Nigeria      9
India        18
Saudi Arabia 9
.
.
.
```

(no matter if there's index from 0 to n at the leftmost column)

Can anyone help me to deal with this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only a single series (a column of data with index values), really, so this works:

```
pd.Series(d, name='Count')
```

You can then construct a DataFrame if you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(d, name='Count'))
df.index.name = 'Country'
```

Now you have:

```
               Count
Country             
Argentina          9
Azerbaijan         5
Brazil             3
...
```

Comment: I agree why you said in efficient, didn't think of pd.Series

Comment: Aweeeeeesome!! Touched by your knowledge! Thanks!

Comment: @John Zwinck also `pd.Series(d, name='Count').to_frame()` just another way of representing

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as a list

```
pd.DataFrame([d]).T.rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

That might get the work done but will kill the performance since we are saying the keys are columns and then transposing it. So since `d.items()` gives us the tuples we can do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()),columns=['country','count'])

df.head()
    country  count
0       Germany      3
1   Philippines      8
2        Mexico      9
3       Nigeria      9
4  Saudi Arabia      9
```

Comment: This is inefficient.

Comment: @John why is this inneficient?

Comment: @joaoavf: It has to do with the internal storage details of Pandas.  This solution is 5x slower than the one in my answer, according to `%timeit`.  Even @jezrael's solution, which looks like it might not be fast, is way faster than this.

Comment: @John Thanks, interesting to know that!

Answer (score 3):

Use `DataFrame` constructor and pass `values` and `keys` separately to columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':list(d.keys()), 
                   'Count': list(d.values())}, columns=['Country','Count'])
print (df)
          Country  Count
0      Azerbaijan      5
1       Indonesia      3
2         Germany      3
3          France     12
4          Mexico      9
5           Italy      2
6           Spain      5
7          Brazil      3
8        Thailand      5
9       Argentina      9
10        Ukraine      3
11  United States     38
12         Turkey      2
13        Nigeria      9
14   Saudi Arabia      9
15    Philippines      8
16          China      1
17          Japan     60
18         Russia      3
19          India     18
20    Netherlands      8
```